# Pipes and callbacks in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm processing some audio using portaudio. The haskell FFI bindings call a user defined callback whenever there's audio data to be processed. This callback should be handled very quickly and ideally with no I/O. I wanted to save the audio input and return quickly since my application doesn't need to react to the audio in realtime (right now I'm just saving the audio data to a file; later I'll construct a simple speech recognition system).

I like the idea of `pipes` and thought I could use that library. The problem is that I don't know how to create a `Producer` that returns data that came in through a callback.

How do I handle my use case?

---

Here's what I'm working with right now, in case that helps (the datum mvar isn't working right now but I don't like storing all the data in a seq... I'd rather process it as it came instead of just at the end):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module Main where

import Codec.Wav

import Sound.PortAudio
import Sound.PortAudio.Base
import Sound.PortAudio.Buffer

import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.ForeignPtr
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.Storable

import qualified Data.StorableVector as SV
import qualified Data.StorableVector.Base as SVB

import Control.Exception.Base (evaluate)

import Data.Int
import Data.Sequence as Seq

import Control.Concurrent

instance Buffer SV.Vector a where
  fromForeignPtr fp = return . SVB.fromForeignPtr fp
  toForeignPtr = return . (\(a, b, c) -> (a, c)) . SVB.toForeignPtr

-- | Wrap a buffer callback into the generic stream callback type.
buffCBtoRawCB' :: (StreamFormat input, StreamFormat output, Buffer a input, Buffer b output) =>
    BuffStreamCallback input output a b -> StreamCallback input output    
buffCBtoRawCB' func = \a b c d e -> do
    fpA <- newForeignPtr_ d -- We will not free, as callback system will do that for us   
    fpB <- newForeignPtr_ e -- We will not free, as callback system will do that for us
    storeInp <- fromForeignPtr fpA (fromIntegral $ 1 * c)
    storeOut <- fromForeignPtr fpB (fromIntegral $ 0 * c)
    func a b c storeInp storeOut

callback :: MVar (Seq.Seq [Int32]) -> PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo -> [StreamCallbackFlag] -> CULong 
            -> SV.Vector Int32 -> SV.Vector Int32 -> IO StreamResult
callback seqmvar = \timeinfo flags numsamples input output -> do
  putStrLn $ "timeinfo: " ++ show timeinfo ++ "; flags are " ++ show flags ++ " in callback with " ++ show numsamples ++ " samples."  
  print input
  -- write data to output
  --mapM_ (uncurry $ pokeElemOff output) $ zip (map fromIntegral [0..(numsamples-1)]) datum
  --print "wrote data"

  input' <- evaluate $ SV.unpack input  
  modifyMVar_ seqmvar (\s -> return $ s Seq.|> input')

  case flags of
    [] -> return $ if unPaTime (outputBufferDacTime timeinfo) > 0.2 then Complete else Continue
    _ -> return Complete

done doneMVar = do
  putStrLn "total done dood!"
  putMVar doneMVar True
  return ()

main = do

  let samplerate = 16000

  Nothing <- initialize

  print "initialized"

  m <- newEmptyMVar
  datum <- newMVar Seq.empty

  Right s <- openDefaultStream 1 0 samplerate Nothing (Just $ buffCBtoRawCB' (callback datum)) (Just $ done m)
  startStream s

  _ <- takeMVar m -- wait until our callbacks decide they are done!
  Nothing <- terminate

  print "let's see what we've recorded..."

  stuff <- takeMVar datum
  print stuff

  -- write out wav file

  -- let datum = 
  --       audio = Audio { sampleRate = samplerate
  --                   , channelNumber = 1
  --                   , sampleData = datum
  --                   }
  -- exportFile "foo.wav" audio

  print "main done"
```

Comment: Can you give some example code of obtaining the data from the call back without pipes?

Comment: Perhaps consider using channels rather than `MVar`s of sequences. They work very well for these kind s of producer-consumer problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `MVar`s to communicate between the callback and `Producer`.  Here's how:

```
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

fromMVar :: (Proxy p) => MVar (Maybe a) -> () -> Producer p a IO ()
fromMVar mvar () = runIdentityP loop where
    loop = do
        ma <- lift $ takeMVar mvar
        case ma of
            Nothing -> return ()
            Just a  -> do
                respond a
                loop
```

Your stream callback will write `Just input` to the `MVar` and your finalization callback will write `Nothing` to terminate the `Producer`.

Here's a `ghci` example demonstrating how it works:

```
>>> mvar <- newEmptyMVar :: IO (MVar (Maybe Int))
>>> forkIO $ runProxy $ fromMVar mvar >-> printD
>>> putMVar mvar (Just 1)
1
>>> putMVar mvar (Just 2)
2
>>> putMVar mvar Nothing
>>> putMVar mvar (Just 3)
>>>
```

Edit: [The `pipes-concurrency` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency) now provides this feature, and it even has a [section in the tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes-concurrency/1.1.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Concurrent-Tutorial.html#g:5) explaining specifically how to use it to get data out of callbacks.

Comment: You can easily use a `Chan` instead, if you want to interleave execution rather than blocking on `putMVar` when the consumer hasn't gotten around to `take`ing the latest value yet. The cost is that you might use more memory.

Comment: That's right.  It depends on whether you want the callback to synchronize with the producer.